# how to implement multi range using MDBRange of mdb-react-ui-kit

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs

[image]
I can see multi range example in normal mdb javascript library,
But I could n't find how to implement multiple range using `MDBRange` component.

It's using `mdb-react-ui-kit`

How to implement multi range using MDBRange, not single range.

This is what I tried

```
         <MDBRange 
            multiple={true}
            min={1}
            max={100}
         />
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple range?

Answer (score 0):

Range slider requires MDB pro essential package as it is stated [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/multi-range-slider/).
If you wish to use the range slider, you need to purchase it.